# Export Graph to "Full Size" (as I see on screen)

Tags: graphics, export, pdf-format

```
blankDo[name_, xmin_, xmax_, ymin_, ymax_] :=   blank[name] =    Graphics[GridLines -> {Range[xmin, xmax], Range[ymin, ymax]},     GridLinesStyle -> {{Opacity[1/2], LightGray,        Dashed}, {Opacity[1/2], LightGray, Dashed}},     PlotRange -> {{xmin - 0.2, xmax + 0.2}, {ymin - 0.2, ymax + 0.2}},      AxesStyle -> {{LightGray, Dashed}, {LightGray, Dashed}},     Frame -> True,     FrameTicks -> {Range[xmin, xmax], Range[ymin, ymax]},     ImageSize -> Full];

blankDo["elf", -13, 13, -17, 20]
```

Works fine on screen.
[image]

Save it manually (right clicking)
[image]

"Good" quality.

But if I want to use it in `Export`

```
Export["a.pdf", blankDo["elf", -13, 13, -17, 20]]
Export["a.pdf", blankDo["elf", -13, 13, -17, 20], ImageSize -> Full]
```

Both produced "bad" quality graphs,
[image]

Tried `ImageResolution`. Did not work.

Comment: I would just highlight the output cell bracket, choose `Save Selection As...` and get a faithful `PDF` export that way. Using `Export` usually produces `PDF` that requires disproportionate effort to get a good look.

Comment: @Jens If it is just a couple of graphs, I wouldn't mind doing it that way. But I am hoping to Export a lot of them in batches.

Comment: Things seem to work better if you *don't* use `ImageSize -> Full`.  Try `ImageSize -> 900` and see if you like the result.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard hmmm okay for 'this' graph, but not good for a general solution, especially when my end game is to export/save batches of these files.

Comment: Could you explain how using explicit `ImageSize` in your `Export` would be a problem in batch usage?  It seems `Export` needs this information to work reasonably well.  Are you also exporting graphics with a fixed `ImageSize` (within the `Graphics` itself)?  Perhaps we can check each `Graphics` for its `ImageSize` value and if it is `Full` specify an appropriate fixed size.